System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Error thrown on startup by UserDialogs in MAUI
I have a MAUI app that I am upgrading from Xamarin. For popups we used the Acr.UserDialogs package but ran into some trouble. I tried fixing this problem by upgrading to a MAUI version of this package (Controls.Userdialogs.Maui). Unfortunately, the error persist so I must be doing something wrong.
I get the error:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Controls.UserDialogs.Maui.IUserDialogs' while attempting to activate 'ViewModel'.

The code looks like this
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp(IStartupSpecific startupSpecific)
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            //register fonts
        })
        .UseUserDialogs()
        .RegisterServices(startupSpecific);
        
    // added logging

    var host = builder.Build();

    // register some more services
        
    return host;
}

public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel, IViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(IRemoteConfigService remoteConfigService, IUserDialogs userDialogs) : base(userDialogs)
    {
        // set some commands ready
    }
}

public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected IUserDialogs Dialogs { get; }
    
    protected BaseViewModel(IUserDialogs dialogs)
    {
        Dialogs = dialogs;
    }
}

I tried basically the same thing as with the old acr package, but it resulted in the same error. Now I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Please take some time to edit your post so that it's readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and use the preview to make sure that it's formatted in a way that you'd want to read if you were trying to answer the question.

What is IStartupSpecific? Are you trying to instantiate your ViewModel class before the MauiApp finished initialization by any chance?

Im in the middle of my upgrade from Xamarin so it might be that this is some old leftover code. But looking at it it is a class thats injected based on the platform and contains some methods that add some platform specific services that need to be registered. These services are registered in the RegisterServices method. I dont initialize my viewmodel in this class.

Have you tried the Sample project from Controls.UserDialogs.Maui repository? If there is the same issue? If not, then you are doing smth wrong.

Looking at the README in the repository for Controls.Userdialogs.Maui.
You will want to use this method to initialize the library: UseUserDialogs(registerInterface: true, () => { }) that will register the interfaces, making it available to use with dependency injection and therefore it will resolve when the view model is attempted to be resolved.

Tried this and unfortunately i still get the same error on startup.

I removed the dependency injection and just retrieved the current instance in my base viewmodel like:
protected BaseViewModel()
{
    Dialogs = UserDialogs.Instance;
}

I get a different error so i assume this is the fix. No idea why this isnt injectable ¯\(ツ)/¯.

It is injectable, I'm using this package in one of my own projects.

Does this mean i am still doing something wrong or will this also work? Because for now this seems to work.

That will work, but you have a hard dependency on the UserDialogs.Instance which may cause issues when you want to write unit tests, for example.

Ah yes that is true, i didn't consider this. Well for now i will use this but i will definitely fix this issue.

That's why I provided my answer with the wrapper service. That solves both problems, if the registration of the IUserDialogs interface doesn't work for you.

It should be possible to either do as Gerald already wrote in another answer, or you should be able to register the IUserDialogs service manually:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);

If that doesn't work, you can also wrap the UserDialogs.Instance with your own interface, e.g.:
public interface IDialogService
{
    Task<string> ActionSheetAsync(string message = null, string title = null, string cancel = null, string destructive = null, string icon = null, bool useBottomSheet = true, CancellationToken? cancelToken = null, params string[] buttons);
}

and implementation:
public sealed class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public Task<string> ActionSheetAsync(string message = null, string title = null, string cancel = null, string destructive = null, string icon = null, bool useBottomSheet = true, CancellationToken? cancelToken = null, params string[] buttons)
    => UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheetAsync(message, title, cancel, destructive, icon, useBottomSheet, cancelToken, buttons);
}

and then register:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDialogService, DialogService>();

and use your own service:
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected IDialogService Dialogs { get; }
    
    protected BaseViewModel(IDialogService dialogs)
    {
        Dialogs = dialogs;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel, IViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(IRemoteConfigService remoteConfigService, IDialogService dialogService) : base(dialogService)
    {
        // set some commands ready
    }

    public async Task ShowSomeActionSheet()
    {
        await Dialogs.ActionSheetAsync("Hello");
    }
}

